# Inclusion-exclusion error clarification

Tags: probability

Suppose you pick a number between $1$ and $30$ uniformly at random. Let $A$ be the event that
the number is even. Let $B$ be the event that the number is divisible by $3$. Let $C$ be the event that the number
is divisible by $5$. Using the above formula, what is the probability that the number is divisible be at least one
of the values $2, 3,$ or $5$?

$$|A|=15$$
 $$ |B| = 10$$
 $$ |C| = 6$$

From what I have worked out

$$P(A) = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$P(B) = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$P(C) = \frac{1}{5}$$
$$P(A \cap B) = \frac{1}{6}$$
$$P(A \cap C) = \frac{1}{10}$$
$$P(B \cap C) = \frac{1}{15}$$

I am using the formula of inclusion=exclusion

$$ P(A ∪ B ∪ C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) − P(A ∩ B) − P(A ∩ C) − P(B ∩ C) + P(A ∩ B ∩ C)$$

When I add it all up I end up with $P(A ∪ B ∪ C) = 1.03$

How is that possible? Logically, there are 8 numbers that would not divide by $2,3,5$ Thus, if you take the opposite, there should be $\frac{22}{30}$ probability that you would get a number divisible by $2,3,5$. So what am I doing wrong?!

Comment: How did you end up with $1.03$ using those values? $$\tfrac 1 2+\tfrac 13+\tfrac 15-\tfrac 16-\tfrac 1{10}-\tfrac 1{15}+\tfrac 1{30} = \tfrac {11}{15}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is wrong with your arithmetic:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac12&+\frac13+\frac15-\frac16-\frac1{10}-\frac1{15}+\frac1{30}\\\\
&=\frac{15+10+6-5-3-2+1}{30}\\\\
&=\frac{22}{30}\;,
\end{align*}$$

just as it should.